# Time series modeling in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have got a question about modeling time series in R.
My data consist of the following matrix:

```
1   0.03333333 0.01111111 0.9555556
2   0.03810624 0.02309469 0.9387991
3   0.00000000 0.03846154 0.9615385
4   0.03776683 0.03119869 0.9310345
5   0.06606607 0.01201201 0.9219219
6   0.03900325 0.02058505 0.9404117
7   0.03125000 0.01562500 0.9531250
8   0.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
9   0.04927885 0.01802885 0.9326923
10  0.06106870 0.02290076 0.9160305
11  0.03846154 0.00000000 0.9615385
12  0.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
13  0.06028636 0.03843256 0.9012811
14  0.09646302 0.05144695 0.8520900
15  0.04444444 0.06666667 0.8888889
```

This matrix has in total 200 rows.

As you can see, in each situation the sum of each row is 1, that is because the values are the percentage of a whole. For example row 1 contains 3.33% of variable a, 1.11% of variable 2 and 95.5% of veriable 3.
the first column indicates the year that the values are measured.

My goal is to make a prediction for the next 5 years, so from year 200 to 205.

I can do that by making three normal time series forecast. But for that forecast the total sum is never equal to 1, which is very important. 
Normally, I use techniques like arima and exponential smoothing.

Does somebody know a method to make a forecast for such a problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though I am no expert in R, the question seems to hint towards providing an algorithm for the problem. Show us what you've tried and what problems are you getting.

Comment: you should move this function to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` are the three columns then predict `B=log(b/a)` and `C=log(c/a)`.  Then recover `a`, `b` and `c` as `a = 1/(1+exp(B) + exp(C))`; `b = exp(B)/(1+exp(B)+exp(C))` and `c = exp(C)/(1+exp(B)+exp(C))`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, what you suggested works. but I was verifying why it is working. can you maybe explain why it works or a give a link where I can find the reason?

Comment: `a+b+c = 1/(1+exp(B)+exp(C)) + exp(B)/(1+exp(B)+exp(C)) + exp(C)/(1+exp(B)+exp(C)) = (1+exp(B)+exp(C))/(1+exp(B)+exp(C)) = 1`. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you need to make a [statistical Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)); subtracting each estimated score from the estimated mean, then dividing the result by the estimated standard deviation. This would gurantee that your forecast values lie in the range [0-1].